# Bootstrap 3 custom header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a second set of eyes to look at my twitter bootstrap 3 header. I would welcome some insight on the code structure and methodology as it relates to bootstrap best practices and efficiency.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      #navbar-xs { min-height:35px; border-radius:0; margin-bottom:10px; border-bottom: solid thin #ddd;} 
      #navbar-xs .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle { border-color: none;}
      #navbar-xs .navbar-toggle { padding:0;}
      #navbar-xs .navbar-brand { padding: 8px 0px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; height: 30px; } 
      #navbar-xs h4.navbar-brand { margin: 0px; } 
      #navbar-xs .navbar-nav > li a { padding: 0px 10px; margin:8px 0;}
      #navbar-xs .navbar-nav > li + li a { border-left:1px solid #ddd;  }

      #mainNav .container { margin-bottom: 12px;}
      #mainNav.navbar-default { background-color: transparent; border-width: 0;}
      #mainNav .nav { padding: 30px 0 0 20px;}
      #mainNav .navbar-nav > li > a { padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;}
      #mainNav .navbar-brand { float: none; padding: 0; margin: 10px 0; width:250px; }
 
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      #navbar-xs h4.navbar-brand { font-size: 14px; padding:6px 5px; } 
      #navbar-xs .navbar-brand { width: 280px;}

      #mainNav .navbar-brand { padding:0 60px 10px; margin:0; width:100%; height: auto; }
      #mainNav .nav, .navbar-collapse { padding: 0; margin:0; border-width:0;}
      #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav { background-color: #f3f3f3; border-width: 0;}   
    }

   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Start navbar-xs Top Navigation -->
<nav id="navbar-xs" class=" navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <h4 class="navbar-brand">
        Place Main Tagline Goes Here - 
        <small>Sub Tag Here</small>
      </h4>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Company Name</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></l>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i>
            1-800-555-1234
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            Search
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin:5px; width:300px;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                  </button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Customer Service <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Link One</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Link Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Section Two</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- End navbar-xs -->

<!-- Start mainNav Navigation -->
 <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">    
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <div class="navbar-brand" align="center">
                <a href="/">
                    <img class="img-responsive " src="http://placehold.it/350x70">
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
            <!-- toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <div class="row visible-xs"> 
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x10">
            </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li> <a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1200x10" alt="">
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

- There's an "i" missing from facebook `</li>` tag (you can
  leave out the closing tags completely).
- Since you declared HTML5 doctype, avoid using `<i>` and `<b>` for icons as they have semantic meaning, use `<span>` instead.
- `align=""` attribute is deprecated, use css instead.
- don't use `<li class="divider"></li>` elements, use css instead.
- don't use `<small>` for styling purposes, use `<span>` and css instead.